# What is the correct way to draw straight lines using raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, grid, drawing, raphael

I'm having trouble drawing a simple grid using raphael.js.

I'm using paper.path(), and everything looks fine with my path strings :
[image]

but somehow this gets rendered :
[image]

here's the code I'm using to render this "grid"

```
    // vertical lines
    for(var x = (this._offset.x % cellSize); x < this.width; x += cellSize){
        var vpath = "M " + x + " 0 l " + x + " " + this.height + " z";
        var vline = paper.path(vpath);
    }
    // horizontal lines
    for(var y = (this._offset.y % cellSize); y < this.height; y += cellSize){
        var hpath = "M 0 " + y + " l " + this.width + " " + y + " z";
        var hline = paper.path(hpath);
    }
```

(In this case cellSize = 50, and this._offset = {x:0, y:0})

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're assuming **l** takes an absolute coordinate, but it actually takes a relative one.  When you write:

```
M 50 0 l 50 600
```

You're thinking it means *write a line from (50,0) to (50, 600)* but it actually means *start at (50, 0), move (50, 600)*.  Hence the skewed grid.

You just need to write the vpaths like this (replacing **x** and **y** after the **l** with **0**):

```
var vpath = "M " + x + " 0 l 0 " + this.height + " z";
```

and:

```
var hpath = "M 0 " + y + " l " + this.width + " 0 z";
```

Comment: Thx bro, I can't believe i missed something so simple.

Comment: you've got the concept right, but mixed up the semantics: the difference between absolute and relative commands is by specifying uppercase letters for absolute (`L`) or lowercase for relative (`l`).